# Complex Fourier Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have found the complex Fourier series for my desired force. I now need to find the steady-state forced vibration of my oscillator as a Fourier Series. (The particular solution to the inhomogeneous differential equation) How can I go about finding this.

Answer (score 1):

You should know the solution for an oscillator driven by a single $e^{i\omega t}$. Since the equation is linear the solution for a superposition of such forces is just the superposition of the individual solutions.

If you have a family functions $x_n(t)$ which satisfy the harmonic oscillator differential equation for driving forces of the form $F_n(t)= c_n \exp(in\omega t)$, i.e,

$$ m\ddot{x}_n + k x_n = c_n e^{i n\omega t}, $$

then the solution to,

$$ m\ddot{x} + k x = \sum_n c_n e^{i n\omega t}, $$

Is the sum of the $x_n$'s,

$$ x(t) = \sum_n x_n(t) $$.